# Using the Thrust library for CUDA for an array reduction

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cuda, thrust

I am using thrust to find the sum of an array ,c, but I keep getting compiler error "error: expresion must have class type"

```
float tot = thrust::reduce(c.begin(), c.end());
```

This is the code line that isn't working, c is a float array and is the element sum of 2 other arrays.

Cheers

Comment: A "float array"? You don't mean a C-style array `float c[]`, do you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

c should be a `thrust` type, such as `thrust::host_vector` or `thrust::device_vector`.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to pass pointers to `thrust::reduce`.
If you have a pointer to an array in host memory, you can do something like this:

```
float tot = thrust::reduce(c, c + N); // N is the length of c in words
```

If your pointer is to an array in device memory, you need to cast it as a `thrust::device_ptr` first:

```
thrust::device_ptr<float> cptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(c);
float tot = thrust::reduce(cptr, cptr + N); // N is the length of c in words
```

Answer (score 3):

There's an example for thrust::reduce on the [Thrust github page](https://github.com/thrust/thrust). You can't call .begin() on a plain old array since it's not an instance of an object, i.e. it's meaningless. As an example, it'd be like calling .begin() on the array "b" in the code below.

```
int main(void)
{
    thrust::host_vector<float> a(10);
    float b[10];

    thrust::fill(a.begin(), a.end(), 1.0);
    thrust::fill(b, b+10, 2.0);

    cout << "a: " << thrust::reduce(a.begin(), a.end()) << endl;
    cout << "b: " << thrust::reduce(b, b+10) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about if the array "b" is allocated using cudaMallocManaged() ?